# what's the best practice to update many registers of one model with one form in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I think it should exist an easier way than I use:

In the view:

```
<%=form_tag({action:"update_many")%>
  <% @revisions.each do |r| %>
    <%= fields_for "revision[]",r do |revision_builder| %>
      <%= revision_builder.text_field :any_field %>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

In the controller:

```
def update_many
  @revisions=Revision.where(...)
  @revisions=@revisions.update(params[:revision].keys,params[:revision].values)
end
```

( and if I want to use   `params.require(:revision_X).permit(:prevision_Y: [:field,:field])` I need to add another `fields_for` just after `form_tag`... but this is another history )

**Can I use `form_for` for update many records of a model? using one line instruccion... or something else**

Thanks